# C++ Описать класс «Работник» c динамическим массивом

Tags: c++, классы

Описать класс «Работник» c динамическим массивом.
Каждая запись содержит фамилия и инициалы, должность, год поступления на работу, зарплата. 
Предусмотреть возможность формирования: списка с клавиатуры и из файла, печати всего списка сотрудников; списка работников, стаж работы которых на данном предприятии превышает заданное число лет; списка работников, зарплата которых больше заданной; списка работников, занимающих заданную должность.
Ребята, хелп, не понимаю классы. Пишу динамический массив в мейне, а в функциях его не видно, не понимаю вообще. Горю, в понедельник сдавать с отчетом(( кое-что пытался сделать, скидываю:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




using namespace std;

class Worker {
    public:
        Worker(string family="" , string inicial="" , string dolzh="" , int year=0 , double zp=0 ); 
        void printListEmployees(int)  ; 
        void printListEmployeesOverYear(int); 
        void printListEmployeesOverSalary(double); 
        void printListEmployeesThisPosition(string); 
        ~Worker();

    private:
        string  family;
        string  inicial;
        string  dolzh;
        int year;   
        double zp;
};


/*========================== KONSTRUKTOR ==========================*/

Worker::Worker(string family , string inicial , string dolzh , int year , double zp )
        {
        cout<<"Введите фамилию работника  "; cin>>family;
        cout<<"Введите инициалы работника  "; cin>>inicial;
        cout<<"Введите должность работника  "; cin>>dolzh;
        cout<<"Введите год поступления на работу  "; cin>>year;
        cout<<"Введите зарплату работника  "; cin>>zp;

        }
Worker::~Worker(){
        int n;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                delete workers[n];
            }
        delete[] workers;
                }
/*========================== FUNCTION ==========================*/
void Worker :: printListEmployees(int n) // печать списка сотрудников
        {   

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)

                cout<<family;

        }




/*========================== MAIN ==========================*/

int  main(){

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

        int n;
        cout<<"Задайте количество работников"; cin>>n;
        Worker *workers = new Worker[n];
        Worker s;
        cout<<s.printListEmployees();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сотрудник у вас один (каждый экземпляр `Worker` содержит лишь одну порцию данных о работнике), а вы пытаетесь работать с ним, как со списком.

Посему `printListEmployees` должна быть свободной функцией (не членом `Worker`) такого вида:

```
void printListEmployees(Worker* workers, size_t count)
```

И память должна уничтожаться в том же скоупе, где и выделяется (деструктор не нужон, это должно быть в `main`)

Comment: хорошо, попробую. а что за site_t?

Comment: @adam_k, описка) `size_t` - это обычно эквивалент `unsigned int`.

Comment: поможете мне еще?

Comment: @adam_k, если у вас будут интересные вопросы, то вы можете обратиться ко мне в комментариях нового вопроса и мне придет нотификейшн